# Update with psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a problem with my code. When I connect to the database and want to execute a PSQL code line I get an error that says:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "ew444" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE produkt_info SET antal = 4 WHERE modellnr = EW444
```

... even though I have "ew444" in my table

I've tried with the code below but it does not work for some reason. I can't figure out what the problem is.

```
con1 = connect()
con1.execute("UPDATE produkt_info SET antal = 4 WHERE modellnr = 
EW444")
```

I appreciate your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to put `EW444` in quotation marks. `con1.execute("UPDATE produkt_info SET antal = 4 WHERE modellnr = 'EW444'")`. Also, you have inconsistent use of capitalisation in your question `'EW444' != 'ew444'`but that won't itself cause an error, you just won't get any matches

Answer (score 1):

This treats both `modellnr` and `EW444` as columns names:

```
UPDATE produkt_info SET antal = 4 WHERE modellnr = EW444
```

You can see that from the error which says:

> ***column** "ew444" does not exist*.

If you want to compare `modellnr` to string value `'EW444'`, you need to put it in quotes:

```
UPDATE produkt_info SET antal = 4 WHERE modellnr = 'EW444'
```

Answer (score 0):

> con1.execute("UPDATE produkt_info SET antal = 4 WHERE modellnr = %s", ('EW444',))

HTH